# How to split a CamelCase string in its substrings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, split

I have a nice CamelCase string such as `ImageWideNice` or `ImageNarrowUgly`. Now I want to break that string in its substrings, such as `Image`, `Wide` or `Narrow`, and `Nice` or `Ugly`.

I thought this could be solved simply by

```
camelCaseString =~ /(Image)((Wide)|(Narrow))((Nice)|(Ugly))/
```

But strangely, this will only fill `$1` and `$2`, but not `$3`.

Do you have a better idea for splitting that string?

Comment: What would you want done with `ThisIsANarrowImageOfHIV?` Make a join with n, or split up HIV?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
s = 'nowIsTheTime'

s.split /(?=[A-Z])/

=> ["now", "Is", "The", "Time"]
```

`?=pattern` is an example of *positive lookahead.*  It essentially matches a point in the string right before *pattern.*  It doesn't consume the characters, that is, it doesn't include *pattern* as part of the match. Another example:

```
    irb> 'streets'.sub /t(?=s)/, '-'
=> "stree-s"
```

In this case the `s` is matched (only the second `t` matches) but not replaced.  Thanks to [@Bryce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090202/bryce-anderson) and his [regexp doc link.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html) Bryce Anderson adds an explanation:

> The`?=`at the beginning of the`()`match group is called *positive
>   lookahead,* which is just a way of saying that while the regex is
>   looking at the characters in determining whether it matches, it's not
>   making them part of the match. `split()`normally eats the in-between
>   characters, but in this case the match itself is empty, so there's
>   nothing [there].

Comment: During my tests this regex results in `["", "Now", "Is", "The", "Time"]` if the first letter is an uppercase letter. What do I wrong?

Comment: splash: I tried it in 1.8.7 and 1.9 and it worked on NowIsTheTime. With what language/version did you get the zero-length first element?

Comment: Sorry @DigitalRoss, I forgot to mention that I tested with RegexBuddy. But I wonder why this is valid in Ruby? Java also gives an empty String for the first array element: `"NowIsTheTime".split("(?=[A-Z])")`

Comment: You could always just add `reject {|x| x.empty? }`

Comment: No, not necessary, it works fine in Ruby. It was with Java and with RegexBuddy that splash had troubles.

Comment: Missing from the answer is an explanation of why it works, for people still trying to grok regular expressions.  Maybe someone will find this useful:

The ?= at the beginning of the () match group is called "positive lookahead," which is just a way of saying that while the regex is _looking_ at the characters in determining whether it matches, it's not making them part of the match.

split() normally eats the in-between characters, but in this case the match itself is empty, so there's nothing "in between."

[Regexp docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html)

Comment: To deal with CamelCase with acronyms such as S.M.Mousavi asked about, see [my alternative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48019684/383737).

Answer (score 38):

I know this is old, but worth mentioning for others who might be looking for this.  In rails you could do this:  `"NowIsTheTime".underscore.humanize`

Answer (score 14):

DigitalRoss's answer is correct as it handles the general case where you do not know whether it's strict camel case (first character lower case) or Pascal case (first letter upper case).

If you know which of these forms the string is in, or you want to force one or the other, Inflector can do it.

For Pascal case:

```
"NowIsTheTime".titleize
```

For camel case:

```
"nowIsTheTime".titleize.camelize :lower
```

Comment: Important to note, `#titleize` and `#camelize` are strictly Rails methods, and not in core Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
camelCaseString =~ /(Image)(Wide|Narrow)(Nice|Ugly)/
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Event though this is a Ruby regex question and the [answer by DigitalRoss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997516/how-to-split-a-camelcase-string-in-its-substrings-in-ruby/3997552#3997552) is correct and shines by its simplicity, I want to add a Java answer:

```
// this regex doesn't work perfect with Java and other regex engines
"NowIsTheTime".split("(?=[A-Z])"); // ["", "Now", "Is", "The", "Time"]

// this regex works with first uppercase or lowercase characters
"NowIsTheTime".split("(?!(^|[a-z]|$))"); // ["Now", "Is", "The", "Time"]
"nowIsTheTime".split("(?!(^|[a-z]|$))"); // ["now", "Is", "The", "Time"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
I/p:- "ImageWideNice".scan(/[A-Z][a-z]+/).join(",")

O/p:- "Image,Wide,Nice"
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from [DigitalRoss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3997552/383737) will not recognize acronyms embedded in the CamelCase. For example, it will split "MyHTMLTricks" into "My H T M L Tricks" instead of "My HTML Tricks".

Here is another option based on the `AsSpaced()` function in [PmWiki](http://www.pmwiki.org), which does a great job of being sensitive to cases like this:

```
"MyHTMLTricks" \
.gsub(/([[:lower:]\\d])([[:upper:]])/, '\1 \2') \
.gsub(/([^-\\d])(\\d[-\\d]*( |$))/,'\1 \2') \
.gsub(/([[:upper:]])([[:upper:]][[:lower:]\\d])/, '\1 \2')

=> "My HTML Tricks"
```

The other thing I like about this approach is that it leaves the string a string, instead of transforming it into an array. If you really want the array, then just add a split at the end.

```
"MyHTMLTricks" \
.gsub(/([[:lower:]\\d])([[:upper:]])/, '\1 \2') \
.gsub(/([^-\\d])(\\d[-\\d]*( |$))/,'\1 \2') \
.gsub(/([[:upper:]])([[:upper:]][[:lower:]\\d])/, '\1 \2') \
.split

=> ["My", "HTML", "Tricks"]
```

For the record, here is the original PHP code from PmWiki.

```
function AsSpaced($text) {
    $text = preg_replace("/([[:lower:]\\d])([[:upper:]])/", '$1 $2', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/([^-\\d])(\\d[-\\d]*( |$))/', '$1 $2', $text);
    return preg_replace("/([[:upper:]])([[:upper:]][[:lower:]\\d])/", '$1 $2', $text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def solution(string)
  final_str = []
  string.chars.each do |x|
    final_str << " "  if x.upcase == x 
    final_str << x
  end
  final_str.join
end
```